# Disable Toggle with JQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am using the `.prop('disabled', true);` property but it does not seem to be working.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
$('#checkboxSelectedQ1').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(".checkboxSelectedQ2").prop('disabled', true);
  }
```

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that checkboxSelectedQ1 and checkboxSelectedQ2 are both toggles

Comment: Really hard to tell without seeing the other parts of your code like the HTML. Are you sure you're suppose to use a class selector in `$(".checkboxSelectedQ2")`. I just find it weird that you have an element with an ID of `checkboxSelectedQ1` but not Q2.

Comment: Please read: [it's not working is useless](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).   Does nothing happen?  Have you checked it enters the change event?  Does it disable, but not enable? (as you've mentioned `toggle` but only `set` the property)?   Have you checked your selectors `console.log($(".checkboxSelectedQ2").length)`?  Can you provide [mcve] - ie include the HTML - as noted above, it maybe an id -vs- class issue.  Your [code works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/kcgtqs5o/) *as provided* (extrapolating the HTML)